# Does Someone Actually Sell icons using cracked versions of illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I have seen Crack of Photoshop and ILLustrator available like most of the time and in my country they were teaching photoshop using cracked versions of it people were using it on offices cracked versions of it no was paying a single penny i mean can an icon be guessed that it was built using cracked versions of adobe software

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  No doubt some people do used cracked software, but you shouldn't. It's not only illegal, and immoral because it's stealing, it is also often dangerous. Cracked software more often than not contains viruses.Also there is no shortage of legal safe alternatives, such as free Open Source software. Adobe software isn't required to sell designs you have created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking if one can tell if an icon was created in an unlicensed version of a software? If so, the answer is *probably not*.

I don't think that the software leaves a code in the files one creates that exposes that it was created in an unlicensed (cracked) version.